# How can I use double quotes and colons in a http.Get Request as query string?

Tags: go

I would like to send this rest call ...

```
GET http://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:"ch.viascom.groundwork"+AND+a:"foxhttp"&rows=100&core=gav
```

... but can't because it gets encoded to

```
http://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?core=gav&q=g%3A%22ch.viascom.groundwork%22%2BAND%2Ba%3A%22foxhttp%22&rows=20
```

This is my go function:

```golang
func searchOnMavenCentral() {
    var groupId = "ch.viascom.groundwork"
    var artifactId = "foxhttp"

    params := url.Values{}
    params.Add("q", `g:"` + groupId + `"+AND+a:"` + artifactId + `"`)
    params.Add("rows", "20")
    params.Add("core", "gav")

    resp, err := http.Get("http://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?" + params.Encode())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    log.Println(resp.Request.URL)
    log.Println(resp)
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Thx for your help in advance!

**Updated state**

With your help I managed to create the desired URL, but I'm facing the following new issue now:

```
&{400 Bad Request 400 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Connection:[keep-alive] Date:[Mon, 05 Aug 2019 23:56:45 GMT] Server:[nginx/1.14.1]] 0xc00011a080 -1 [chunked] false false map[] 0xc0000d4000 <nil>}
```

This is the updated code:

```golang
func searchOnMavenCentral() {
    var groupId = "ch.viascom.groundwork"
    var artifactId = "foxhttp"

    qp := "q=g:\"" + groupId + `"+AND+a:"` + artifactId + `"` +
        "&rows=20" +
        "&core=gav"

    u := &url.URL{
        Scheme:   "http",
        Host:     "search.maven.org",
        Path:     "/solrsearch/select",
        RawQuery: qp,
    }

    resp, err := http.Get (u.String())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    log.Println(resp.Request.URL)
    log.Println(resp)
}
```

Comment: The percent encoding in the second snippet is the correct encoding of `:`, `"` and other special URL octets.  Does the server have a problem with the encoding?

Comment: Yeah, it's absolutely clear that this would be the correct encoding. But https://search.maven.org/classic/#api accepts it only with the unencoded quotes and colons :(

Comment: Then the API is broken unfortunately, as unescaped double-quotes are not permitted in URIs: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2 you'll have to do your own handling of the string since you are looking to intentionally create an invalid URI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that server does not handle percent encoding, use basic string operations to construct the URI.

To work around the decoding and encoding of URLs by the net/http package, use the URL.Opaque field to specify the URI.

```
func searchOnMavenCentral() {
    var groupId = "ch.viascom.groundwork"
    var artifactId = "foxhttp"

    qp := "q=g:\"" + groupId + `"+AND+a:"` + artifactId + `"` +
      "&rows=20" +
      "&core=gav"

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://search.maven.org", nil)
    req.URL = &url.URL{
       Scheme: req.URL.Scheme,
       Host: req.URL.Host,
       Opaque: "/solrsearch/select?" + qp,
    }
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    log.Println(resp.Request.URL)
    log.Println(resp)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your awesome help. But I think that _Opaque_ just replaces the host as well and then I get this:
`http:/solrsearch/select?q=g:"ch.viascom.groundwork"+AND+a:"foxhttp"&rows=20&core=gav` But it helped me out to create the desired URL with RawQuery. Now the GET url looks as it should be, but I arrived at a new error:
`&{400 Bad Request 400 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Connection:[keep-alive] Date:[Mon, 05 Aug 2019 23:56:45 GMT] Server:[nginx/1.14.1]] 0xc00011a080 -1 [chunked] false false map[] 0xc0000d4000 <nil>}`

Comment: It looks like you called [URL.String](https://godoc.org/net/url#URL.String) to get `http:/solrsearch/select?q=g:"ch.viascom.groundwork"+AND+a:"foxhttp"&rows=20&core=gav`.   The net/http package calls [URL.RequestURI](https://godoc.org/net/url#URL.RequestURI) to get the request URI, not  URL.String. The RequestURI method does the right thing for this scenario (it ignores Host and Scheme). See [this playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/Iq-8UGevkld) for how the request is rendered on the wire.

Comment: Regarding the 400 response:  a) The issue may be something other than the encoding  b) Is there an nginx reverse proxy in front of the server? If so, is it possible that the nginx is percent encoding the request URI?